AWS Patch manager applies wrong OS patches
I use AWS SSM Patch Manager to apply patches. Today I changed some EC2 AMIs from Centos7 to Amazon linux2, but the patch manager is still applying Centos patches. After applying, the OS of the instance changed to Centos7 from Amazon Linux 2. I tried creating a Pacth group and linking the AMZN2 Linux patch baseline to them, setting the Patch Group:  tag on my instances, but it didn't help. How can I do it?
